# Restrict New Relic for some namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, admin, restriction, newrelic

I want to disable New Relic on the /admin namespace, so I'll have reports only from the user part of the app?

I'm using it on Rails with gem and heroku config

Answer (score 2):

You can block New Relic from instrumenting Rails controllers by calling `newrelic_ignore` in the controller class. You can also block individual actions by passing `:only` and `:except` options, like with Rails filters.

See the [Ruby agent documentation on blocking instrumentation](https://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/blocking-controller-instrumentation) for details.

Comment: Another way is to set a rule `rules.ignore_url_regexes` with routes you want to ignore

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/ruby-agent/installation-configuration/ruby-agent-configuration#rules-ignore_url_regexes